# Kaffir Lime from seeds

Tags: seeds, citrus

I tried to smuggle a kaffir lime tree in from Malaysia in December, sadly it died instantly when I potted it.

My partner bought 3 limes in France and brought them in but there was no seed in them.

So I have written to a friend in Malaysia asking her to send me some seeds. She is positive that people grow it from seeds in her native Kelantan.

Who has any experience growing them from seeds? My climate zone is 12a, average temperature is between 20 and 30 ºC NEVER above 34º C, very stable, humidity is very high with about 1850mm annual rainfall and a strong wind all year round. All big citrus trees grow fine here as long as they don't get attacked by the leafcutters and parrots (fruit only).

Comment: I don't think we are allowed to advise someone how to break the law. Can't you get seeds or livestock without smuggling?

Comment: I don't want to know how to smuggle them, seeds are legal. Trees aren't

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: I am in Central America, 780m above sea level. Pretty much like the Highlands in Malaysia

Answer (score 4):

I have grown Kaffir limes from seeds and been very successful. It took a kaffir lime tree about 4 years to bear fruit.
I have also grown a kaffir lime plant from a small branch. It was slow growing but it did work.

Comment: Tank You all2 tears later or je atoll Alice growing vert slowly